# Android: Open a fragment or activity that is part of current activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, audio

I have a playlist of songs where I provide options like play/pause, stop, lyrics. I am using MediaPlayer class to play my audio. I normally pause or stop the audio when the activity goes into onPause() or onStop() state or if my activity has lost the audio focus.

I want that when the user opens the lyrics which can be loaded in a new activity or fragment, the audio does not stop playing. So it should never call the onPause() or onStop(). I know that I can do it by using ActivityManager and get info about the foreground activity and then handle it in my onPause() and onStop().

But I was trying to figure out a more elegant and proper way to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you thought about displaying the lyrics inside of a custom alertdialog? that takes away pause or stop..

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I'll try that out and let you know. However, I always thought that a dialog will but the current activity in Pause state because the state of the activity will go from Active to Visible. But I'll check this out

Thanks